# How do you avoid missing data when using limit, orderBy, and startAfter with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Isn't it true that you could miss data if what you are ordering by does not have a unique value?

For example if I have a function that says:

```
export async function getCities(){

  const result = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('cities')
  .orderBy('population', 'desc')
  .limit(5)
  .get();

  const CityResults = result.docs.map((city)=> ({
    ...city.data(),
    docId: city.id
  }));
```

if I limit to 5 and my last piece of data has a population of 1000, my `getMoreCities()` funciton would say

```
startAfter(1000)
```

But say there were 7 cities with a population of exactly 1000, you would miss the data on both of your firestore calls.

It seems silly you cant `startAfter(documentId)`

is there a workaround?

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/nervg9/not_being_able_to_startafter_a_document_id_seems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore implicitly adds the document ID to each query where you specify an anchor document, so if you pass in a `DocumentSnapshot` it will already work.

You should also be able to pass the document ID as the last argument to your `startAfter` variant, although I must admit I always use the `DocumentSnapshot` for this purpose myself.

Here's an example of what this would look like:

```
citiesRef.orderBy("population").startAt(860000).limit(1).get().then((snapshot) => {
  var lastdoc;
  snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log("1: "+doc.id);
    lastdoc = doc;
  });
  citiesRef.orderBy("population").startAfter(lastdoc).limit(1).get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log("2: "+doc.id);
      lastdoc = doc;
    });
  });
});
```

Working version: https://jsbin.com/sibimux/edit?js,console

Comment: Would you mind an example of using Document Snapshot for this purpose?

Comment: You mean `startAfter(lastDocumentSnapshotOnPreviousPage)`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startafter for the relevant overload.

Comment: I added an example of this to my answer, and linked a jsbin where it runs.

Comment: Using the whole snapshot as a startAfter paramater worked like a charm! Thank you!